# How to get Name of IRaster object using ArcObjects?

Tags: raster, arcobjects

I have an IRaster object as output from a function. I need to be able to get the name of that raster. Is there a way that I can do that? I know that I can't mask an IRaster as an IRasterDataset. If I could, I would be able to get the Name property from that (I think). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish the above this way . . .

```
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IRasterLayer rasterLayer = new RasterLayerClass();
        rasterLayer.CreateFromRaster(raster);
        string sRasterName = rasterLayer.Name;
```

Comment: If possible, you might consider having your function output an IRasterLayer or IRasterDataset rather than an IRaster.